# IOS App Submission with UK English as default Language

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, submission

So I'm submitting my app to iOS through iTunes connect.
I noticed that the name I wanted for my app was taken when the default language was set to 'English', but when I changed the default language to 'UK English' the name became available. 
Now I want to know if by choosing 'UK English' as my app's default language if this will be a hindrance/problem? 
For example, will my app be hidden for some users when they search for the term?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a wise idea to use a name that has already been used / is currently in use. This will definitively lead to bugs or unwanted occurrences. Every entry on your app on the net will be shared with someone else's application.

I would therefore suggest to come up with another name for your app.

Comment: After searching numerous times, I can't see any app on the iTunes store with the same name.
Plus, on the Google Play Store thousands of apps shares their name as there is no requirement from Google for the name to be unique.

Comment: Well as I said, you shouldn't only think about what you *have* to do or what you *can't* do. I think you should ask yourself how necessary that certain name is and whether you might need some unique one. But that's what I think.